# HTML&CSS: Выпадение float-элемента с заданной относительной шириной из строки

Tags: html, css

Допустим, мы создали несколько блоков, задали им относительную длину и зафлотили их влево (ссылка на [исходный код](https://jsfiddle.net/6adfzjaf/)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.object{
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 9px 15px;
}

.red{background-color: #800000;}
.yellow{background-color: #DAA520;}
.green{background-color: #6B8E23;}
.blue{background-color: #4169E0;}
.teal{background-color: #008080;}
.purple{background-color: #4B0082;}
```

```html
<div class="object red"></div>
<div class="object yellow"></div>
<div class="object green"></div>
<div class="object blue"></div>
<div class="object teal"></div>
<div class="object purple"></div>
```

Какова причина, по которой несмотря на задание относительной ширины, на определённых ширинах экрана происходит выдадение правых блоков из потока?

Проблема ещё и в том, что эта самая "ширина выпадения" у каждого браузера своя.
Конкретно в моей задаче, выпадение блоков - приемлемо, но оно должно происходить на одной и той же ширине окна для всех браузеров, чтобы смог настроить медиазапросы.

Comment: Ну у каждого браузера свои `padding` у  `body`... попробуй обнулить их
а так же отступы между блоками наверное фиксированной ширины......
Проверь что занимает то место, которого не хватает и происходит выпадание

Comment: Мне кажется причина в пиксельных margin. Вообще лучше делать контейнеры 33.3333333% c padding.

Comment: @ pepel_xD, это я сделал; [таким вот](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) образом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое происходит из-за того, что `margin` не входит в указанную вами относительную ширину `width: 30%`. То есть блок сначала возьмет указанную вами ширину `width`, а потом добавит к ней `margin`. Фактическая ширина блока(то есть с учетом отступа) в данном случае станет больше `30%`.

Почему блоки спрыгивают не сразу, а в какой-то определенный момент?
Вы предполагаете, что в строку должно входить три блока. В таком случае ширина одного блока будет `100/3 = 33.3333%`. Вы же указываете ширину `30%`. Получается остаток `3.3333%`. Тк в строке у вас три блока, то итоговой свободное место(остаток) составляет `9.9999%`. Когда у вас браузер растянут на всю ширину, то указанная вами сумма абсолютных `margin: 0 9px 15px;` всех трех блоков укладывается в этот остаток.
Сжимая браузер вы уменьшаете абсолютную величину в пикселах вашего остатка `9.9999%` и в какой-то момент он становится меньше суммы отступов, что и переносит блок вниз.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробное объяснение! ...Что же делать, если border в декоративных целях уже задан и его нельзя использовать в качестве фиктивного отступа? Ведь нет такого значения box-sizing, которое учитывает margin.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, оберните блоки. И уже обертки флочте с бордером прозрачным

Comment: Хорошо, думаю на этом вопрос закрыт. Ещё раз благодарю Вас за качественное объяснение!